# How WHM Detects, Where to Move the Request when multiple Cpanel are there in WHM based on root IP

Tags: server, cpanel, whm

I just received credentials of a WHM and can see multiple Cpanel accounts there. All Cpanels are based on same IP. I'm wondering how server detects where to send request and how server defferentiate the requests between domains as all cpanels have Same IP. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's called VirtualHosts or `vhosts`!!! Check Apache's configuration file `httpd.conf` in cPanel. You can run as many virtualHosts on any machine as you may like...

Comment: thanks @Ankesh for yout time. where could i find httpd.conf in my WHM ?

Comment: You will find httpd.conf file at /usr/local/apache/conf directory. Also, you should not edit it because cPanel will overwrite it sometime later. You can find more information about VirtualHosts in Apache docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/